# Reset wordpress password on AWS lightsail

Tags: wordpress, amazon-lightsail

I’ve used wp all in one plugin to migrate my site to aws lightsail. However, it also migrated the old credentials which was owned by the previous webhosting company. I’m not able to obtain those credentials. In this case, how can I reset my user and password to my new Wordpress? My lightsail ssh has a bitanami interface on the console, I suppose that is how I should go about it but I'm exactly sure about the steps.

Comment: So your site is already up and running correctly, but you don't know the username or email of the old admin account, and you just wanted to be able to login to the site?

Answer (score 3):

You should use wp cli for resetting password.

- First install [wp cli](https://wp-cli.org/#installing)
- Run `wp user list --role=administrator` to get administrator user id
- Run `wp user update 1 --user_pass=newpass` to reset password.

Comment: Easy and practical! Thanks!

Comment: Super easy the best one till now, Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

if you have ssh access you can change the password by following MySQL query

`UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass = MD5('your-new-password') WHERE ID = 'any-admin-ID'`

Or if you don't know any administrator account you can create one By

`INSERT INTO wp_users (ID, user_login, user_pass, user_nicename, user_email, user_url, user_registered, user_activation_key, user_status, display_name) VALUES ('4', 'new-username', MD5('your-new-password'), 'Your Name', 'test@yourdomain.com', 'http://www.test.com/', '2021-06-17 00:00:00', '', '0', 'Your Name');`

and assign it as administrator by following queries

`INSERT INTO wp_usermeta (umeta_id, user_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (NULL, '4', 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}');`

`INSERT INTO wp_usermeta (umeta_id, user_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (NULL, '4', 'wp_user_level', '10');`

****Replace `wp_` with your DB prefix***

Answer (score 0):

I tried these codes in Lightsail, but it didn't work, so I found a way.

```
mysql -u root -p bitnami_wordpress -e "..."

mysql -u root -p bitnami_wordpress -e 
"INSERT INTO wp_usermeta(
  umeta_id, user_id, meta_key, meta_value
) VALUES (
  NULL, '4', 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s: 1:"1";}'
);"
```